# Eslint SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: npm, eslint, yarnpkg

I've encountered the following error while using `eslint` command in my project:

```
$ eslint ./src/ --max-warnings 69 --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx

Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.7.0

.../node_modules/language-tags/lib/Tag.js:17
        static ERR_DEPRECATED = 1;
                              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at new Script (vm.js:83:7)
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (.../node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
    at Module._compile (.../node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:184:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (.../node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/language-tags/lib/index.js:11:11)
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I am using the following plugins and configs for eslint:

```json
    {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.15.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.15.2",
        "eslint": "7.7.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "9.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "2.4.0",
        "eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.12.1",
        "eslint-plugin-dirnames": "1.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "2.23.4",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "7.24.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.2.0",
        "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "5.0.3",
        "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "18.0.1"
    }
```

I've tried to reproduce the correct package configuration which worked fine before I started switching my project from `npm` to `yarn v1` (this problem happened because of that). But current `yarn.lock` is about 25000 lines long and it is tough to compare it to `package-lock.json`.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by myself eventually and want to share the solution.
The problem lied in the `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@6.4.1` package.
Its dependencies are listed below:

```
  dependencies:
    "@babel/runtime" "^7.11.2"
    aria-query "^4.2.2"
    array-includes "^3.1.1"
    ast-types-flow "^0.0.7"
    axe-core "^4.0.2"
    axobject-query "^2.2.0"
    damerau-levenshtein "^1.0.6"
    emoji-regex "^9.0.0"
    has "^1.0.3"
    jsx-ast-utils "^3.1.0"
    language-tags "^1.0.5"
```

As it turns out, `yarn v1` resolved the dependency `language-tags@^1.0.5` as `language-tags@1.0.7` which caused the `eslint` command to stop working altogether.

```
language-tags@^1.0.5:
  version "1.0.7"
  resolved ".../npm/language-tags/-/language-tags-1.0.7.tgz#41cc248730f3f12a452c2e2efe32bc0bbce67967"
  integrity ...
  dependencies:
    language-subtag-registry "^0.3.20"
```

So the solution is to either change the version of `language-tags` in your lock file from 1.0.7 to 1.0.5 or provide a [yarn resolution](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) where you would specify the desired package version

```json
    "resolutions": {
        "language-tags": "1.0.5"
    }
```